# Shows that the image of $S$ is $X \setminus \{x_0\}$.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $X$, $S\colon X\to X$ and $x_0 \in X$ be a model of the natural numbers, I know tha a model of natural numbers consists of:

A set $X$,

A distinguished element $x_0 \in X$

An $S\colon X\to X$ function.

Such that the following properties are satisfied:

1. $S(x) \not= x_0$ for all $x\in X$
2. $S$ is injective
3. If $Y$ is a subset of $X$ such that $x_0 \in Y$ and it holds that for all $x \in Y, S(x) \in Y$, then $Y = X$.

But I don't know how to prove that his image is $X - \{x_0\}$

Answer (score 2):

Consider the set
$$\{x_0\}\cup\{y\in X: y=S(x), \text{for some } x\in X\}$$
and show that $Y=X$ using property $3.$